# How to find specific cell containing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have spreadsheet A that is very large (10,000 cells for example).
I also have spreadsheet B.
I want to use a formula that can locate the specific location of data I enter in a specific and store it in a different cell.
What Formula can I use?

Comment: Have a look at the MATCH function `e.g. =MATCH("john", Sheet1!$A:$A)` which will return the row number in column A in sheet1 where the word "john" occurs. Then to return say the value in column B, say "john"'s surname `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH("john", Sheet1!$A:$A))`

Answer (score 0):

*To find specific cell containing data, stored in a different data range in the same or another sheet, you may use formula like this.*

**:Caveat:**

*Since you have not shared any sample data therefore I've assumed data range.*

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$200,MATCH(D1,$A$2:$A$200,1)))
```

- This returns the absolute cell reference of the data stored in `D1`, finds in `A2:A200`.

*If the lookup range is in another sheet then use formula like this.*

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$200,MATCH(D1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$200,1)))
```

- Returns the absolute cell reference of the data stored in `D1`, finds in `Sheet2` in the data range `A2:A200`.

**N.B.** Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.